# A word relating to sad emotional drunkenness

Tags: single-word-requests

I tried googling the word but no success. I recall it was used in a pejorative manner, but it isn't slang, at least in this day and age.

And maybe it even describes a pathetic or morbid rambling of a drunk.

Comment: What word did you Google?

Comment: I googled "drunk, sad, rambling word" to find a hit.

Answer (score 15):

You're probably thinking of ***maudlin***, which relates to the self-pity often expressed in such situations (or which causes the drinking and drunkenness in the first place).

> Self-pityingly or tearfully sentimental: *a bout of maudlin self-pity*
>
> [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/maudlin)

OED has a specific definition at sense 2:

> Having reached the stage of drunkenness characterized by tearful sentimentality and effusive displays of affection; characteristic of (the behaviour of) someone who has reached this stage.

Answer (score 1):

The euphemistic phrase "*tired* and emotional" was popularised by the British satirical magazine *Private Eye* in the 1960's, when describing the state of the Labour cabinet minister George Brown.

You can read about it [here, in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tired_and_emotional)

I particularly like the reference to the Parliamentary usage of euphemism (it's unacceptable to accuse a fellow MP of being drunk). Just goes to show how engrained is the British habit of saying one thing to mean another (often something nasty).

Comment: There's also the expression 'pissed as a newt' (meaning 'drunk') which is adopted with other words to suggest that drunkenness was involved: "He was quite exuberant when he heard the news." "Oh yes, exuberant as a newt."

Comment: I disagree. This whimsical usage as popularised by Private Eye rarely if ever implies ***sad emotional** drunkenness*. It just means "drunk" - and if there's any *specific* aspect of drunkenness, it's usually either *poor physical coordination* (staggering, falling over) or *loud-mouthed, unguarded* (saying stupid things one will regret later).

Answer (score 0):

The adjective *wretched* can be compounded with terms referring to drunkedness.

**Wretched**:

> adjective: (Of a person) in a very unhappy or unfortunate state.

(OED)

eg. "the wretched drunkard"

Comment: So can blubbering, melancholic, pathetic, and myriad other adjectives

Comment: @stevesliva, I originally wrote "is often" instead of "can be" - but thought that if I did that I'd have people commenting on unsubstantiated claims... Personally, I was surprised to see that 'wretch' didn't specifically refer to drunks when I looked it up.

Answer (score 0):

My father is an alcoholic.   When he's in the drunken state, I've always described his behaviour as "melancholy".

Oxford Dictionary Definition:  "A feeling of pensive sadness, typically with no obvious cause".

My father's behaviour has always been self-pitying but never overtly sentimental when drunk - he invariably attempts to argue that others are responsible for his past behaviours or current plight.  So, I would not describe him as maudlin.